# UserData not installing Apache is Instance Security Group Routes Outbound Traffic through ALB

Tags: amazon-ec2, user-data, aws-application-load-balancer

I have following UserData Script in my Launch Template:

```
#!/bin/bash
yum update -y
yum install -y httpd.x86_64
systemctl start httpd.service
systemctl enable httpd.service
echo "This is test html file" > /var/www/html/index.html
```

Security Group 'xAlbSG'is associated with Application Load Balancer with following Rules:
InBound: HTTP:TCP:80, Source = 0.0.0.0/0
OutBound: All traffic: All Protocol: All Port, Destination = 0.0.0.0/0

Security Group 'InstanceSG' is associated with Launch Template (and Instance Launched from Template) with following Rules:
InBound: HTTP:TCP:80, Source = xAlbSG
OutBound: HTTP:TCP:80, Destination = xAlbSG

Problem:
UserData script is not installing apache unless I change the OutBound rule of 'InstanceSG' to
OutBound: All traffic: All Protocol: All Port, Destination = 0.0.0.0/0

Question: Any reason why?

Answer (score 0):

What you have as EC2 Security Group outbound rule "HTTP:TCP:80, Destination = xAlbSG"

Yum, or any package manager, requires "Outbound Internet Access" from the server it is used, which means, you need to setup your outbound destination "0.0.0.0/0".

You can restrict the port 80 or 443, thats what yum/rpm use.